# Generic class type constraint with forward declaration - delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2009, type-constraints

In Delphi 2009, we can use class types as constraint for generic types declaration:

```
type
  TMyBaseClass = class
    //Attributes and methods here
  end;

type
  TMyGenericClass<T: TMyBaseClass> = class
    //Attributes and methods here
  end;
```

But when I need an attribute of type `TMyGenericClass<TMyBaseClass>` declared inside `TMyBaseClass`, a forward declaration is needed to avoid the circular reference/constraint relationship between classes. But in this particular case, the compiler says that the class type is not a valid constraint:

```
type
  TMyBaseClass = class; //forward declaration

  TMyGenericClass<T: TMyBaseClass> = class //the error is highlighted here, with [DCC Error] E2510 Type 'TMyBaseClass' is not a valid constraint
    //Attributes and methods here
  end;

  TMyBaseClass = class
  private
    FObject: TMyGenericClass<TMyBaseClass>; //This is a requirement
    //Other attributes and methods here
  end;
```

Any recommendation to accomplish this task?
Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, the forward declaration is the problem but, at the same time, is the solution for the circular reference/constraint relation =( Anybody has checked if this compiles on newer delphi versions?

Comment: It won't compile on any version. This is the expected behaviour. This is as designed. In any case, even if it did compile, which it won't, the lack of generic variance means your intended design would be of no use.